# OS-less raspberry pi 2 debugging of Assembly language

Tags: pi-2, bare-metal, debug, assembly

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 without an OS installed. I have an assignment where I have to create and display some code in assembly language for the Pi 2.

The lab that we have set up at school has hardware/software that allows us to run and test the code we write. The components include the JTag, something called a JLinkServer and gdb, which I believe to be the main debugging tool.

My question is, is there any software or tools that will allow me to write **assembly code** for the Pi 2 at home on my Windows 7 computer, and test to see if the code will work and also debug it. I would then take this code I have been working with and port it to the raspberry pi when I go back to the lab. Does such software exist? (without needing the Pi 2 connected or anything like that)?

This is basically what we are working with: http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~kawash/RPi/sigcse16.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend taking a look at this site http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/emulate-raspberry-pi-pc/ which describes how to emulate the original raspberry pi on a pc. You then should be able to debug and run assembly code on the emulated raspberry pi that you created.

Comment: that has an OS...

Comment: OS doesn't matter for assembly. Assembly manipulates the CPU directly.

Comment: Just make sure your emulator is for the correct Raspberry Pi :)